# Sending E-Mails from SAP Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-platform

I'm looking for a way to send emails from a Spring Java app deployed in SAP Cloud Foundry. The [documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/e6ff28a3bb571014b89ad0fa2f410a1f.html)  describes how this works for NEO apps.
For Cloud Foundry, there is no corresponding documentation.

**Is it possible to send mails from Cloud Foundry? If so, is there an existing sample?**

Comment: I don't think the s4sdk tag is appropriate here, I don't see how this question relates to the s4sdk. I edited the tags to add the more appropriate cloudfoundry hana-cloud-platform sap-cloud-platform, which is not yet peer reviewed.

Please use the s4sdk tag for questions related to the s4sdk.

Comment: OK, it's not an s4sdk issue, thanks for reassigning.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure destinations in the same way as in Neo. Alternatively, you can use SAP Live Link 365 for E-mail as in the [link](https://livelink.sapmobileservices.com/documentation/#/integrate/apiReferences)